# JAVA: Do i need to rebuild an application after updating password in context.xml?

Tags: java, web-applications

I am new to Java.

I updated the context.xml file on my web app, but it appears to still be using the old password.

Do i need to rebuild an application after updating a DB password in context.xml?

Thanks.

Comment: you ned to package it again, not compile

Comment: The context.xml is part of the war file. Changes to the context.xml need a build process to be reflected in a war file. An IDE might do that for you and maybe even hot swap the file into your application server, but usually the context.xml i read only once during deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, I ended up updating the configurations locally, doing a maven install, and then replacing the war file on the server with the new generated war from my local environment.